# Where can I see a list of Minikube ISO releases?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

It seems the latest version of Minkube has a bug in the DNS resolving of services.

Where can I find a list of ISO releases?

Answer (score 2):

It seems if you just take the version from: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases

And replace the version number in this example URL  it with

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/iso/minikube-v0.23.5.iso
```